# How to select an element from _ngcontent block using protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests

I have below structure for my angular app.

```
<div _ngcontent-c8 class=“page-body”>
  <div _ngcontent-c8 class=“cell-list”>
    <a _ngcontent-c8="" class="cell cell-row ng-star-inserted" 
    queryparamshandling="preserve" ng-reflect-query- params- 
    handling="preserve" ng-reflect-router-link=“/path” href=“/link” 
    </a>
    <a _ngcontent-c8="" class="cell cell-row ng-star-inserted" 
    queryparamshandling="preserve" ng-reflect-query- params- 
    handling="preserve" ng-reflect-router-link=“/path” href=“/link” 
    </a>
    <a _ngcontent-c8="" class="cell cell-row ng-star-inserted" 
    queryparamshandling="preserve" ng-reflect-query- params- 
    handling="preserve" ng-reflect-router-link=“/path” href=“/link” 
    </a>
 </div>
```

How would I select specific a tag from this structure? In the previous version of angular with ng-repeat directive, I could use "(element.all(by.repeater))".However it does not work for the above code.

I tried using element.all(by.css)), but that does not work either. 
Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: element.all(by.tagName('a')) and then either chain that with a .element or use a filter

Comment: so like element.all(by.tagName('a')) .all(by.className('cell-row'))

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
getByAttribute(searchText: string): ElementFinder {
  let container = element(by.css('.page-body .cell-list'));
  return container.all(by.tagName('a')).filter(function(el) {
    return el.getAttribute('href').then(function(value) {
      return value.trim() === searchText;
    });
  }).first();
}
```

This code lists all `a` elements and filters them by it's `href` value. This is an example for showing you how to filter values.